# Custom Email button works for me but not my users

Tags: javascript, custom-button

Afternoon all,

I have a custom button on my Opportunity object to Onclick Execute Javascript to send an email to a specific email address, code below:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/10.0/apex.js")} 

var newRecords = [];
var c = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
c.id ="{!Opportunity.Id}";
c.PMO_Request_Submitted__c = true;
newRecords.push(c);
result = sforce.connection.update(newRecords);
window.location.reload();

location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?retURL=/{!Opportunity.Id}&p3_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}&p24=PMO-IT%26Change@example.co.uk&template_id=00Xb0000000e3nq&p5=');
```

It works absolutely fine for me as an Admin but when my users try and use it the field changes occur and the Opp page refreshes but it doesn't launch the Send Email page. Is there a particular permission that needs enabling to allow this functionality to be used?

Comment: Does your page is accessible for your users ? You can check that in Setup > Permissions set > Pages

Comment: I've access that section but I don't have a Pages permission set. Have I missed setting something up?

Comment: The whole path is : Setup > Manage users > Permission Sets

Comment: Yep, and I'm in there now. There are permissions sets for other aspects of my org but nothing related to Emails or Opportunities or JavaScript. Have I missed something?

Comment: You said `but it doesn't launch the Send Email page`. Do you have this page allowed for your user ? You have a section `VisualForce pages` in the dropdown list.

Comment: Is the email template available for use?

Comment: You shouldn't be reload()'ing *and* redirecting in the same script. Some browsers may choose to honor the last command given (the send to email page), but I'm pretty sure a standards-compliant browser would cease all scripting before that line of code executes, resulting in a simple page reload. I'm not *100%* on this, but I'm pretty sure that's an undefined behavior, left to the implementors of the browser.

Comment: sfdcfox, that's it. I use Google Chrome and don't have an issue, all my users use IE. I've just tried IE and it failed for me too. Forgive my ignorance but I'm not sure how to rewrite the script from how it is currently written. Can you offer any advice?

Comment: I'd pop open the email template editor in a new window first, and reload the current window second. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132122/open-url-in-new-window-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your intent is simply to navigate to the email editor in the same window, remove this line:

```
window.location.reload();
```

In Internet Explorer, any navigation immediately cancels the currently running script, fires the onbeforeunload and onunload events, then navigates. Other modern browsers discard any prior navigation event, which is the same behavior you'd expect if you clicked on multiple bookmarks in your toolbar in rapid succession-- only the last bookmark clicked on would be navigated to.